# Unknown command error when using multithread in notepad compiled by cmd

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new at Java. I am facing a problem when I was trying to run a multi-threading code in cmd. I am using notepad for writing.

```
Error:
Thread.java:1: error: duplicate class: Multi
class Multi extends Thread{
^
Thread.java:6: error: duplicate class: Test3
class Test3 {
^
Thread.java:1: error: cannot access Thread
class Multi extends Thread{
                    ^
  bad source file: .\Thread.java
    file does not contain class Thread
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
Thread.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                n.start();
                 ^
  symbol:   method start()
  location: variable n of type Multi
4 errors
```

```
class Multi extends Thread{
    public void run (){
        System.out.println("thread is running");
    }
}
class Test3 { 
    
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Multi n = new Multi();
        n.start();
        for(int i = 0; i<20; i++){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
                System.out.println("thread is running..."+Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: `duplicate class: Multi` You seem to have created two classes, both called `Multi`.

Comment: *"I am using notepad for writing"*. Why?!? Use an IDE, it will save yu a ton of time and frustration.

Comment: It seems you have multiple source files with classes of the same name in them. Clean up your source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java it is neccessary that the filename corresponds to the name of the class in it. If you name your class 'Thread.java' which is actually a bad idea you need to name the class Thread.
Try renaming your file to 'Multi.java'.

Comment: That is not actual true. A single .java file can contain 1 public class which must match the file name, and multiple package private classes with a different name..

Answer (score 0):

All java code is contained in classes. A single file containing java source code must contain the definition of exactly one public class. In your case, this means that file `Thread.java` must contain the following:

```java
public class Thread {
    // definition of class
}
```

The file can contain other class definitions but they cannot be public classes. Hence file `Thread.java` can contain the definition for class `Multi`. The code could be as follows.

```java
public class Thread {
}

class Multi {
}
```

Another option is to use [nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Note that you should not name your class `Thread` since that is one of the classes in the JDK and having two classes with the same name may cause confusion.

Looking at the code in your question, I suggest creating a file named `Multi.java` that will contain the code for [public] class `Multi`.

```java
public class Multi extends Thread {
    public void run (){
        System.out.println("thread is running");
    }
}

class Test3 {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Multi n = new Multi();
        n.start();
        for(int i = 0; i<20; i++){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
            System.out.println("thread is running..."+Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
        }
    }
}
```